# R Pick First Value Given Condition

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

```
data=data.frame("team"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5),
                "score"=c(4,8,10,3,10,5,4,2,7,7,5,6,5,9,1),
                "trial"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                "sc3"=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
                "sc7"=c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1),
                "sc9"=c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                "sc3trial"=c(-99,-99,-99,1,1,1,2,2,2,-99,-99,-99,3,3,3),
                "sc7trial"=c(-99,-99,-99,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                "sc9trial"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

I have data with column "team" and "score" and "trial". I want to create variables "sc3", "sc7", "sc9", "sc3trial", "sc7trial", "sc9trial" that follow these rules::

The rules are simple for "sc#". Note these are for each group:

> 1. For "sc3": if score <= 3, sc3 = 1. Otherwise sc3 = 0.
> 2. For "sc7": if score <= 7, sc7 = 1. Otherwise sc7 = 0.
> 3. For "sc9": if score <= 9, sc9 = 1. Otherwise sc9 = 0.

The rules are sort of also simple for "sc#trial". Note these are for each group:

> 1. For "sc3trial": If any "sc3" == 1, sc3trial records the trial when it first occurred. If no "sc3" equals to '1' then "sc3trial" equals to "-99"
>      This logic applies the same for "sc7trial" and "sc9trial"

Comment: One confusion, in the title it says pick first value, but in your description, it says `if any "sc3" == 1`.  Can you check my dplyr code.  Is that the expected output

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map` to do the comparison with `score`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(c(3, 7, 9), ~ +(data$score <= .x)) %>%
     set_names(c('sc3', 'sc7', 'sc9')) %>% 
     bind_cols(data %>% select(-c(sc3, sc7, sc9)), .)
```

---

If we have only 3 variables, then

```
data %>% 
   mutate(sc3 = + (score <=3), sc7 = +(score <=7), sc9 = +(score <= 9)) %>%
   group_by(team) %>%
   mutate(sc3trial = c(-99, 1)[(any(sc3 == 1)) + 1],
           sc7trial = c(-99, 1)[(any(sc7 == 1)) + 1]
          sc9trial = c(-99, 1)[(any(sc9 == 1)) + 1])
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
nm1 <- c('sc3', 'sc7', 'sc9')
data[nm1] <- +(data[nm1] <= c(3, 7, 9)[col(data[nm1])])
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch--is there a strictly dplyr way to do it I wonder?

Comment: @bvowe can't we use `purrr`

Comment: Yes of course I was just wondering simply because I never used it before so was wondering if a 'dplyr' solution is viable.

Answer (score 1):

For the first 3 columns the code beloew works, but I didn't uderstand what you want for sc3trial, sc7trial and sc9trial.

```
  data$sc3 = ifelse(data$score <= 3, 1, 0)
  data$sc7 = ifelse(data$score <= 7, 1, 0)
  data$sc7 = ifelse(data$score <= 9, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks  abunch--For the other 3 variables I just want to store the first occurrence for each group of a score that meets criteria. The desired output shows in the dataframe "data"

Comment: Yes, I understood it for sc7trial and sc9trial, but I don't get it for the sc3trial.

Comment: All the sc#trial variables are the same idea

Comment: Why is there 1,2,3 and -99 after the first 1?